# Adding +GMT in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Good day, I would like to ask how can I add any timezone in my date object?

My scenario is I have created a date picker and time picker and they will generate a DateTime Object looking like "01/02/2003 4:56 PM" I just need to add the GMT +/- (Timezone) in the date time object so it can look like "01/02/2003 4:56 PM GMT + 0700" and my backend will process the conversion to utc.

Is it possible? Thank you and good day.

Comment: @Marty thank you, what will I add in my code before i pass the value in my backend application? vm.date = vm.date + '?'

Comment: If you mean you're creating a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, there is a full suite of methods you can use to generate a string with the timezone appended to it.

Comment: @Marty super thanks for your quick reply, and I really appreciate it. I just want to add the GMT in my date object, or should i convert my time in ISO format?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you create a Date object on the client for 1 Feb 2003, it will use the host settings to generate a time value that is UTC. All you need to do is either send that time value to the server (e.g using `date.getTime()`), or generate an ISO 8601 compliant string using the built-in *toISOString* method (which is UTC by defalt).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date("01/02/2003 4:56 PM")` which will return time zone information.

Comment: Parsing of that string is entirely implementation dependent and not reliable. Also, *Date.prototype.toString* is entirely implementation dependent so may be in any (human readable) format and not include any time zone information at all.

Comment: I agree. Parsing strings into Date objects is always not very reliable and one needs to be careful. Thanks for sharing that :)